# Emulated SQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have an arbitrary MySQL query called `query1` that runs on a table `table1` and generates a subset of the rows of that table. From a functional perspective, this query is just yielding a boolean for each row, where if the boolean is `true`, the row is returned in the results, and if it is `false`, it is not (or vice-versa, w.l.o.g.).

Let's also say that I'm taking a JSON blob, parsing it into a row, and adding the row to `table1` every minute. I want to test and see if `query1` returns `true` or `false` on the row immediately after I add it.

Is there a way to perform that test without actually adding the row somewhere in the database and then seeing if the row is returned by the query? My intuition is that it should be possible to 'emulate' the query on the new data without actually adding it anywhere, but I'm not familiar with how (if it's even possible in the first place).

Comment: you could use `EXISTS()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a derived table. E.g.:

```
select max(id) from (select 1 id, 'test' name from dual) as t;
```

In the above example 1 and 'test' represent the row you would need to emulate being present in the table and `select max(id) from t` represent query1.

Comment: Does MySQL have that dual table just like Oracle has?

Comment: @jarlh yes. It's not required though if no tables are references. `select 1 id, 'test'` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL to evaluate expressions without touching any table.

Example:

```
mysql> set @age = 29;

mysql> set @state = 'CA';

mysql> select @age > 30 and @state = 'CA';
+-----------------------------+
| @age > 30 and @state = 'CA' |
+-----------------------------+
|                           0 |
+-----------------------------+
```

This example returns 0 (false) because the `@age` variable is not greater than 30.

You are certainly free to use values you extract from your JSON data (or any other source) as terms in an SQL expression like this.

It isn't required to use user variables as I showed in my example above. You can just use literal values too. I just showed using variables because it might be more clear to test your query conditions if you use variable names that match your column names.